# Inconsistency of data when seen on VF Page and Sites in Date Format

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, date

The Date format when we are seeing the data in VF page is DD/MM/YYYY and when same is viewed from the sites the format is MM/DD/YYYY. Below is the code snip.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!wrpPhaseList}" var="PrPhase" id="theRepeat">
    <tr >
        <td style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; text-align: center">
            <apex:inputField value="{!PrPhase.WrelPhase.End_Date__c}" onchange="selectOnChange('{!$Component.chkbox}'),Validateonchange('{!$Component.PhaseSpr}','{!$Component.End_DateSpr}','{!$Component.ComplitionSpr}');" id="End_DateSpr"  onclick="Validateonchange('{!$Component.PhaseSpr}','{!$Component.End_DateSpr}','{!$Component.ComplitionSpr}');"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did some research and found that this happened due to the difference in the local of the guest user using the site and the system administrator user.